# File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name ' ' is not defined in ATOM

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

It's weird because my code works fine in online python interpreter but when I run it in linux mint with Atom, I have this error message when I enter a word:

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'lol' is not defined
```

Here is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

word = str(input(" Enter a word : "))
reverse = word[::-1]
if reverse == word:
  print("it is a palindrome, félicitation : ")
else:
  print(" it is not a palindrome : ")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using `raw_input` instead of `input`. It sounds like in the online interpreter you might be running the code in Python 3, in which `input` behaves like Python 2's `raw_input`, and using Python 2 locally.

In python 2, `input` results in your code looking for a definition for your input, rather than taking it as a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works fine, but the real problem is that I figure out that I am using python 2 in atom instead of python 3.  I use help() to find which version I use. I am not a pro.