# Can eval function be used in concatenating a string and an integer?

Tags: python-3.7

## I need to know if i am providing a=3 and b=kite then the output should 3kite but it is showing an error, plz help me through this...

```
a=eval(input("enter a number:"))
b=eval(input("enter second data:"))
c=(a+b)
print("the result is:",c)
```

Comment: Just remove both the eval and it will work as expected. `input()` returns a string in python3

Comment: error is to do with `input` read it.. eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object

Comment: Seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567471/file-string-line-1-in-module-nameerror-name-is-not-defined-in-atom

Comment: Thanks, got my mistake.